# How to populate data in a 2d array or matrix is of string data type

Tags: java

I want to store some output from a given sentence in a table format . I am declaring a string matrix where column size is 3( which is mentioned) and name of the columns are [Serial number, Token Name, Occurrences]. My row size is not fixed as it will be based on input sentence. in Token name i.e 2nd column I need to mention Duplicate word, Unique word,Punctuation,Special character and number based on given input sentence. 3rd column is occurrences of corresponding tokens in that input sentence.

Unique word count variable : Unicount
Duplicate word : Counter
Punctuation : PuncMarks
Number : number
Special character:

And how to count Special character?

```
 String input ="Hello world, welcome to java programming; Hello world. 
              what is your age? is it 82? Mail at abc@gmail"    
 int count; 
 int unicount;
 int counter=0;
 int total=0;

 //Converts the string into lowercase  
 input = input.toLowerCase();  

 String words[] = input.split("[\\s,;?]+"); 

 String words2[] = input.split("[\\s,;?]+"); 

 for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { 
     System.out.println(words[i]); 
 }

 System.out.println("Duplicate words in a given string and their occurences: ");   
 System.out.println(input); 
 for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {  
     count = 1;  
     for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++) {  
         if(words[i].equals(words[j])) {  
             count++;  
             //Set words[j] to 0 to avoid printing visited word  
             words[j] = "0";         
         }  

     }  

     //Displays the duplicate word if count is greater than 1  
     if(count > 1 && words[i] != "0")  {
         System.out.println(words[i]+"--"+count);
         counter=counter+1;

     }
 } 
 System.out.println("total duplicate words " +counter); 

 System.out.println("Unique words in a given string : ");   
 for(int m = 0; m < words2.length; m++) {  
    unicount=1;
     for(int n = m+1; n < words2.length; n++) {  
         if(words[m].equals(words2[n])) {  
            unicount++;  
            words2[n] = "0";

         }  

     }  

     //Displays the duplicate word if count is greater than 1  
     if (unicount == 1 && words2[m] != "0") {
         System.out.println(words2[m]+"---"+unicount);
         total++;
     }
 }

 System.out.println("total unnique words " +total); 

 int PuncMarks=0;
 int number=0;

 for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {  
     char a = input.charAt(i);
 if(a == ',' || a == '?' || a == '.' || a==';') { 

     PuncMarks++;  
 } 

 else if (Character.isDigit(a)) {

     number = number + 1;
       }
 }

  System.out.println("Total number of punctuation characters exists in string: " +PuncMarks);  
  System.out.println("Total number in string: " +number); 

 //************Put in a table or 2d matrix***********//


int rowsize=input.length();
String[][] stringmat = new String[rowsize][3];
String title = "Serial number  token name  occurence";
String heading[] = title.split("  ");

System.out.println("Final String matrix is : ");

for(int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++) {
    System.out.print(heading[j]+ "\t");
}
          for (int i = 0; i < rowsize; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++) {
         System.out.print(stringmat[i][j]+ "\t");   
        }
     System.out.println();
 }

}
}
```

Hello world, welcome to java programming; Hello world. what is your age? is it 82? Mail at abc@gmail

```
 Serial Number      token           occurrences
1             unique word            11
2             duplicate word          3
3             Punctuation             5
4             Special character       1
```

Comment: Instead of constructing 2 string arrays and comparing, it'd be much simpler if you constructed a HashMap and count the occurrences.

Comment: I have no issue with counting occurrences. I am trying to form a matrix and populate those data with i,j index. as mentioned in expected output position (0,0) (0,1) (0,2 ) consist of string serial number ,token,occurrences respectively..  How to put these values to a matrix ?